# Minimum number of points inside circle to ensure that at least one distance between any of those two points is less than $1/4$?

Tags: geometry

There are $n$ points distributed randomly inside a circle of radii $r$, in this case, 1.

Find the minimum number of points that have to be generated to ensure that at least there is one distance between any of those points that is less than $k$, in this case, 1/4.

Comment: http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1946-03.pdf

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't think that is relevant. It talks about the minimum number of unique distances in a set of $n$ points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not easy finding the minimum value of $n_k$. This approach gives you an upper bound on the value of $n_k$.

Claim: If we have 81 points, then there are 2 of them whose distance is at most $\frac{1}{4}$ apart.

Proof: Around each of these 81 points, construct a circle with radius $\frac{1}{8}$. All of these circles can be contained with a circle of radius $\frac{9}{8}$. Since $ 81 \times \pi \left( \frac{1}{8} \right)^2 = \pi \left( \frac{9}{8} \right)^2$, this implies that 2 of the circles must overlap. (Note that the mini circles cannot perfectly fill the large circle, so the overlap doesn't occur on the perimeter.) The centers of these 2 circles will then within $\frac{1}{4}$ of each other. $_\square$

You can look at a triangular grid to see how many points you can place, which will give you a easy lower bound. But the true lower bound can be hard to exactly determine.

Comment: From: http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci64.html, it appears that the minimum number must be at least 65.  (The image shows that it's possible to fit 64 non-overlapping radius 1/8 circles inside a radius 9/8 circle.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson We need the circles to have a radius of $1/8=.125$, which  (assuming that the site is correct) shows that we can only have [50 circles](http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci50.html).

Comment: No, we want radius 1/9 in a circle of radius 1.  Or rather radius 1/8 in a circle of radius 9/8, as you use in your answer.

Comment: Equivalently, take a look at the distance column on this page: http://hydra.nat.uni-magdeburg.de/packing/cci/cci.html#Applications.  We're looking for the first N for which the distance is less than 0.25, and that's N = 65.

Comment: By the way, no need to assume the site is correct:  the coordinates are given, so you can easily verify yourself that 64 is possible.  Whether it's possible to fit 65 circles in is another matter:  the site only claims to have the best packings found to date, and it's perfectly possible that there are better ones.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah yes, I forgot about the scaling. 1/9 makes sense now. Thanks! I'm slightly amazed the the answer is about $8^2$, though that's much more of a coincidence.